# How to detect bot message/user message?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots

My FB-NodeJS-API prototype is not working correctly because my webhook is receiving the bot respond which is then sent to API.AI.

I need to set a condition where only a user's message should be received on the webhook request or only user's message should be sent to API.AI.

Can anyone advise me on this?

Comment: Message data contains `sender` and `recipient` properties – what more do you need?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the problem better?  Please add the relevant code.

The bot response should go the user, not the webhook.  The user input will come to the webhook.

I would suggest getting the bot to work without API.AI first and then adding support.  My bot is in node.js so you may just want to jump to the source code.

For more information on setting up a bot see my article [Facebook Bots for Fun and Profit](https://medium.com/@matthewericfisher/facebook-bots-for-fun-and-profit-490245c3797c)

The example bot is [DMS Software Bot](https://m.me/dynamicmemorysolutions)

The source code is [Github fb-robot](https://github.com/matthewericfisher/fb-robot)